# Cannot import certificate to AWS ACM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-certificate-manager

I need to import a certificate to AWS ACM but I'm facing an issue with limit excess although I have never used ACM before. Did I do something wrong or miss any steps?

```
Sorry!
You have reached the maximum number of certificates. Delete certificates that are not in use, or contact AWS Support to request an increase. Choose Previous button below and fix it.
```

Screenshots:
[image]
Error
[image]

Comment: What command are you executing to receive that error message?

Comment: I used AWS management console (web gui)

Comment: How many ACM certificates are already there ? Can you go to Trust advisor service limits and there check if you get some alert regarding these certificates/

Comment: I do not have any certificates.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: https://console.aws.amazon.com/trustedadvisor/home?region=us-east-1#/category/performance Check the limit here

Comment: @IshaaRora I don't see that particular limit there.  I see "Server Certificates" but this is the old IAM service for server certs.

Answer (score 3):

Your account probably has a limit of 0 ACM certificates allowed in your region.

Please see this AWS forum post: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=773934

The original user needed to contact AWS support to increase the limit to 10.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will contact AWS support to increase limit.

Comment: I'm curious, as https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-limits.html, the default limit of imported certificates is 100.

Comment: Yes that should be the default. However, the behaviour you're seeing is showing a limit of 0. So it may be an account mis-configuration, or it may be something else. Best to contact the experts at AWS :)

Comment: @AnNguyen on the page you linked, see **Note**
*"Although the preceding table indicates that an account can own up to 100 ACM Certificates, new AWS accounts might start with a lower limit."*  If the account is very new, this will probably fix itself within a few hours.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, My account has been opened for six months

Comment: @AnNguyen that seems a little more unusual. Let us know what support says.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, Supports don't say anything regarding root cause of my issue. Supports just increase limit as request.